# The graph of units and definitions

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, definition, network, unit-of-measure

Definitions of units (like other definitions) induce dependency graphs between the defined units. For instance, Wikipedia displays the following ones for [the International System of Units (SI), before and after the 2019 redefinition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit):

[image: Old SI]         [image]

My questions are:

- are there bigger examples of unit systems represented as such graphs?
- would it make sense to collect large sets of unit definitions for building such graphs?
- what kind of information may we expect from such representations?
- could we build similar dependency graphs for key concepts in (some areas of) mathematics, and then ask similar questions?

For instance, it seems to me that [Euclid's Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements) may lead to an interesting such graph, and colleagues already did [much work on their proposition dependency graph](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/euclid21-euclids-elements-for-the-21st-century).

I wonder if non-trivial isomorphic sub-graphs, particularly dense sub-graphs, or often repeated patterns (motifs), for instance, would have an interesting meaning in such graphs.

Sorry if this question is too broad.

Comment: The questions about units are more about science than math, and I expect their answer to be something like "the point of the SI base units is so all other scientific units can be written in terms of them, so there is very little to be gained from extending this". Whether or not I'm right, I think you should take the units part to a science site.

Comment: For the other question about math, does [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403770/26369) cover what you're asking? If not, can you edit to clarify what sort of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you @MarkS. The question you mention is indeed much related, thank you. I am more interested in _concepts_ (definitions), though, and in what can be done from such graphs (in addition to nice pictures).